# Error "Invalid marker:null" with CloudBerry Backup and Amazon Glacier

Tags: backup, amazon-glacier, cloudberry

I'm using CloudBerry backup on Amazon Glacier.
After migrating to a new workstation the restoring of files is failing with the below error. I tried using CloudBerry S3 to access the glacier vault but same error. How can this be fixed?

```
2017-03-12 14:49:28,760 [CL] [13] ERROR - Idly running finished with error for command Copy; Source:us-east-1/...../ (us-east-1/Archive/dgS_sEF8q1Fkqa4012rosbhUj9DMRi_0lcSgdQ); Destination:D:\Temp\
CloudBerryLab.Base.Exceptions.BadRequestException
Invalid marker: null
   at rL.B(rG )
   at rL.b(rG )
   at rL.C(rG )
   at rM.II(rG )
   at aFG.aFI.MoveNext()
   at aFn.aFp.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at aFn.A(ICancelable )
   at aFD.a(ICancelable )
   at aFD.jV(ICancelable )
   at XT.A(Object )
CloudBerryLab.S3Client.Glacier.Exceptions.GlacierWebException
**Invalid marker: null**

System.Net.WebException
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at rL.A(rG )
```

Answer (score 1):

That was caused by some API changes on AWS side. However, in new release everything works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

NA: But food for thought..

I have the same error ((400) Bad Request / Invalid marker: null) with 2 clients using different versions of CloudBerry Explorer connected to 2 separate AWS accounts. Neither using AWS: us-east

I called CloudBerryLabs (CBL) support number. The person redirecting calls stuttered something about this being a known issue and also stuttered something about it being an issue with an API. They also said something like CBL was working to remedy the problem or issue a software update.

Comment: Thanks.. not good news but hopefully it is fixeable

Answer (score 0):

Follow up;

I received an e-mail from CBL support informing me of a new release of CloudBerry Explorer for AWS.

I downloaded and installed, at one location where, it appears to be working.

Arjan, CBL have made a revision CloudBerry backup available on 2017/03/14.

WBW

Comment: No need to create a new answer for a follow-up. You can edit your previous answer or ass information as a comment.

Comment: what is the version/build number?